# Terminate unowned workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I'm currently using WF with multiple hosts. If one of these hosts owns a workflow, but crashes, I'd like another host to be able to terminate the workflow. Is there any way to do this?

What I've tried so far is to first remove ownership by executing a sql query to set ownerID and ownedUntil to NULL, unlocked to 1, and nextTimer to the current date. Then I get the workflow instance from the runtime and call terminate on it. This only seems to work when the host that starts the workflow is the one that terminates it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I try my current solution against a workflow started by another host, it does successfully remove the tracking information, but not the instance state.

Comment: @Dan: if you have forgotten something use the edit option on the question and make your change to the question itself.  Content on SO is not immutable.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Thanks. I saw that after I added the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. I call Terminate twice on the workflow instance. I still don't understand why that is needed, but it seems to work.